# MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_COMMITTER_NAME

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to get GIT_COMMITTER_NAME value in my jenkins declarative piepline.

```
echo "Git Commiter  ${env.GIT_COMMITTER_NAME}"
echo "Git Commiter  ${GIT_COMMITTER_NAME}"
```

but getting following error, where as $GIT_COMMIT and  $GIT_URL providing values as per expectations

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_COMMITTER_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:42)
```

As per documentations of Git Plugin

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_NAME - The name entered if the "Custom user name/e-mail address" behaviour is enabled; falls back to the value entered in the Jenkins system config under "Global Config user.name Value" (if any)
```

I verified on my machine

```
$ git config --global user.name
imran raza khan
```

Comment: Is this after you have done a git checkout via the plugin step?

Comment: i am using declarative pipeline where checkout done implicitly. i am able to get value for $GIT_COMMIT

Comment: I don't know declarative sorry!